# Android SDK downgrade issue : compileSdkVersion 24 --> 22

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

**Below Error we get while we downgrade compile SDK version from 24 --> 22**

```
/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/doctorTablet/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
    Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
    Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
    Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
    Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDoctorTabletArmeabi-v7aDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
   compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tratagroup.irx"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 11//version code is 10 for 1.1.15. To be changed while publishing to google play
    versionName "1.1.16"
    multiDexEnabled = true
```

**dependencies in app/build.gradle below**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `values-v23.xml` ?

Comment: This is intermediate file generated which we have deleted many times but as soon as we do clean and build it is generated again.